# Normalization constant for $f(x) = \exp(-x^\alpha)$

Tags: measure-theory

If $f$ is a density with respect to Lebesgue measure given by $k e^{-x^\alpha}$, $x > 0$, then what constant $k$ makes $f \cdot m$ a probability measure?

I need to compute $\int_0^\infty \exp({-x^\alpha})\, dx$, right? I do not see how I have developed the tools to do that, but perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Let $x = u^{1/\alpha}$. Then $dx = (1/\alpha)u^{\frac{1}{\alpha} - 1}\, du$ and

$$\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^\alpha)\, dx = \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^\infty \exp(-u)u^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}\, du = \frac{1}{\alpha} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) = \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{\alpha}\right).$$

Therefore

$$k = \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{\alpha}\right)}.$$