# Normalization constant for $e^{-x^a}$ for all real values $x$

Tags: integration

I've seen this post here on a very similar problem I have:
[Normalization constant for $f(x) = \exp(-x^\alpha)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556914/normalization-constant-for-fx-exp-x-alpha)

I am trying to find the normalisation constant for $f(x) \propto e^{-x^a}$ for $-\infty < x < \infty$, where $a$ is a positive integer.

$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{a}} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-x^{a}} dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{a}} dx 
$$

However, the limits are different for this first term, I don't think I can swap the limits since one is infinite. Does anyone know how I can do this in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by $x^a$ when $x<0$ and $a$ is not an integer (e.g., $a=\sqrt{2}$)?

Comment: @user10354138 sorry, I'll edit the original post, I meant to say $a$ was always a positive integer

Comment: When $a$ is odd, the integral diverges at $-\infty$.  When $a$ is even, your constant is double the constant for $\int_0^{+\infty}$.

Comment: If $a>0$ is even the integrand is even and you just use the other post.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you, this helps a lot. I was making the mistake that I was negating the first term and swapping limits but I can't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sollution if a is odd because the integral diverges at $-\infty$. You can decompose the integral if and only if it exists. If $a$ is even, $e^{-x^{a}}$ is an even funtion so $e^{-x^{a}} = e^{-(-x)^{a}}$
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-x^{a}} dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{a}} dx = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{a}} dx
$$
From the question you linked, you can figure out that:
$$I=2\cdot\Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$$